# Filtering out correlation values in seaborn corrplot

Tags: seaborn

I'm using the `corrplot` function in seaborn and everything works flawlessly.  However, I want to do a little filtering on the data.  Is there a way to hide correlations below or above a certain value? I have a large data frame and I only want to see correlations greater than an arbitrary number, say .4.

[image: corrplot]

I'd like all the 'squares' in the image that are not greater than .4 to be set to white, grey or some other color.  I'm not sure how to do this because the `corrplot` takes a full data frame and calculates the correlations internally. I don't want to filter on the data frame values, just the resulting correlation values.

Maybe there's some way to get the resulting image from the underlying `matshow` call back to my own code and then replot it by filtering the image itself?

Comment: I'd use [`sns.heatmap`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/dataset_exploration.html#visualizing-matrices-with-heatmap). You'll have to compute the correlation matrix yourself, but it's otherwise more flexibly in presentation and allows you to pass, e.g. a mask to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks!  I just noticed `sns.heatmap`, never knew that existed.  I've only recently started using seaborn.  Thanks for the great work!

Answer (score 0):

As per @mwaskom's comments, you can use `sns.heatmap()`. You'll have to compute the correlation matrix yourself, but it's otherwise more flexibly in presentation and allows you to pass, e.g. a mask to do exactly what you want.